# Install jomres on azure cloud

Tags: php, azure, joomla, azure-web-app-service

I'm try'n to install Jomres (free core/web-installer) on a Joomla running at azure(trial). 
The goals it to evaluate the possibility. 
The script installer runs step 1 ok. download the jomres in to the jomres folder.
Step two fails with:

- $_server['pathinfo'] null property in ../init_config_vars.php line 70
- 86 * messages about empty property in ../jomres_config_site_singleton.class line 109

It does not create the jomres tables

EDIT: Also, I am asked in red if this is anew install, or upgrade and a cont button.
Selecting either one does not work.

I tried creating them manually from a local MySql jomres install, no luck. The error is nodisplayed ~170 times

I tried using _server [request_uri], with no luck

Has anyone be able to install jomres @ azure and could share some insight?

PS: I'm try'n to evaluate the possibility of hosting jomres at Azure. I don't have the full version with support yet and I'm not going to buy jomres to get support to be told it won't work.

EDIT:
As I posted in the comment, before I realized I should have just edited my post. I am not married to the use of Azure and Jomres. I have yet to find a Joomla booking component with Jomres features and actually working as advertised.

Comment: This is a pre-sales question, you don't need support to ask it! Jomres is not a Joomla MVC component, it's a standalone application packed to work with Joomla, so there are many considerations that fall outside of Joomla experience you find here. That said, why jomres? why azure? I see, you are trying to make your life harder.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Riccardo Zorn: I did send an email 2 jomres but so far with no answer. Azure to try cloud, I'm not married to it.

Comment: I am also not married to the use of jomres, but I have not yet found a Joomla booking component actually doing what jomres does AND/OR actually working. IF you don't mind sharing any alternatives, I am for sure listening @Riccardo Zorn. I need the commission and subscription payment as well as users must be able to post one or more properties.

Comment: In my experience, Wolly will give you plenty of support on everything; and the product is by far the most complete for Joomla. The problem - which led me away from it - is the steep learning curve when you want to change it and the ugly framework it's built on. I am a developer, and I always end up needing to make changes to the code, so I ended up using simpler products and adding what I need.  But if you're fine with the functionality it offers, it's definitely a good product and it's well supported.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like jomres has a few [prerequisites](http://manual.jomres.net/requirements.html) which you may need to enable in Azure Websites. You can find out about which [PHP extensions](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#default-php-extensions) are enabled by default at the Azure.

You may be required to [enable php extensions](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#enabling-php-extensions) or [bring your own runtime](http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#bring-your-own-runtime) to enable the `--with-calendar` option.

Comment: This is a very informative link in any-case, thank you very much. As the installer passed its own validation of the server in step one, I was hopping I would not have to start digging at that level. But I give it a try, thanx @SyntaxC4

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at the LoC that it references in the error to see if that surfaces something